# LINQ Check if any element in a group of arrays IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am grouping my arrays and checking their length to be same and no array is null.

```
//Create arrays by comma delimiter
string[] woptelwosoitemno_List = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(distinct_WO_Parts_Row.Wop__tel_wo_soitemno) ? 
                                   distinct_WO_Parts_Row.Wop__tel_wo_soitemno.Split(',') : null;
string[] woptelwosoiteminstalledqty_List= !string.IsNullOrEmpty(distinct_WO_Parts_Row.Wop__tel_wo_soiteminstalledqty) ? 
                                   distinct_WO_Parts_Row.Wop__tel_wo_soiteminstalledqty.Split(',') : null;

//Group all arrays
string[][] allArrays = new string[][] { woptelwosoitemno_List, woptelwosoiteminstalledqty_List};

//Check all array length are the same
var arrayLength = allArrays.GroupBy(x => x.Length);

//Check all arrays are not null
var arrayNull = allArrays.GroupBy(x => x == null);
```

However, I am now trying to check if any of the elements in all arrays `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Is there an elegant way of achieving this? *(as I have a lot more arrays in my group)*

Below is my current code:

```
if ((woptelwosoitemno_List.Any(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)))
     || (woptelwosoiteminstalledqty_List.Any(a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter out the sub-arrays that are null, then use `SelectMany` to flatten it. Then you can use `Any` on that.

```
string[][] arrays = ...;
bool arrayContainsNull = arrays
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .Any(string.IsNullOrEmpty);
```